# Function to check the input number of words

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need help to create a function that returns TRUE or FALSE. TRUE - if type 1 or 3 words (like '__hello_', '_hello', '_hello my frend' - spaces should be cut), if the condition is not fulfilled FALSE

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.nazvFac(@f nvarchar(30))    
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @l int = 1, @s nvarchar(30), @i int = 0, @b bit
WHILE LTRIM(RTRIM(LEN(@f))) >= @l  --error here, but I do not know how to fix it
BEGIN                                   
    SET @s = SUBSTRING(@f, @l, 1)
    IF @s BETWEEN 'А' AND 'я' 
        SET @l += 1
    ELSE IF @s = ' '
    BEGIN
        SET @l -= 1
        SET @s = SUBSTRING(@f, @l, 1)
        SET @s = RTRIM(@s) 
        SET @l += 2
        SET @i += 1
    END
    ELSE
        BREAK
END
IF @i = 0 OR @i = 2 
    SET @b = 'TRUE'
ELSE
    SET @b = 'FALSE'
RETURN @b
END
GO
```

Comment: "*Gentlemen programmers*" => there are programmers who are ladies too, you know!

Answer (score 2):

`WHILE LTRIM(RTRIM(LEN(@f))) >= @l  --error here, but I do not know how to fix it`

`LEN()` returns an int, which you are then passing to a string function: `RTRIM()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should trim the string and then check the length.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.nazvFac(@f NVARCHAR(30))    
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @l INT = 1, @s NVARCHAR(30), @i INT = 0, @b BIT

    WHILE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@f))) >= @l  --I think youn need to trim the string and then check length
        BEGIN                                   
            SET @s = SUBSTRING(@f, @l, 1)
            IF @s BETWEEN 'А' AND 'я' 
                SET @l += 1
            ELSE IF @s = ' '
            BEGIN
                SET @l -= 1
                SET @s = SUBSTRING(@f, @l, 1)
                SET @s = RTRIM(@s) 
                SET @l += 2
                SET @i += 1
            END
            ELSE
                BREAK
        END
    IF @i = 0 OR @i = 2 
        SET @b = 'TRUE'
    ELSE
        SET @b = 'FALSE'
    RETURN @b
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to return TRUE only if there are one or three words? This should do it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.nazvFac(@f NVARCHAR(30))    
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @l INT, @b BIT

    SET @l = LEN(@f) - LEN(REPLACE(@f, ' ', '')) + 1
    IF @l == 1 OR @l == 3
        SET @b = 'TRUE'
    ELSE
        SET @b = 'FALSE'

    RETURN @b
END
```

Also, JC. is right about the len() error.